Unit-testing xamarin.mac (net8.0-macos) platform-specific code
I have Xamarin.Mac (net8.0-macos, no MAUI) class library with a lot of platform-specific code (so I can't change the TFM to the cross-platform net8.0) and I want to write some unit and integration tests for this library.
So, I created an empty xUnit test project, changed the TFM to the net8.0-macos... and got the compilation error saying that ApplicationId is required. And after I added the ApplicationId property, I got the next error saying error MSB4044: The "ResolveNativeReferences" task was not given a value for the required parameter "Architectures".  which I don't know how to fix.  I get the same error for the NUnit project.
I found the 8 year old question Xamarin.mac unit test project which says that the macOS build process contains a lot of custom steps and the normal unit tests runners can't handle this. The guiunit which was recommended in the answer is no longer supported anymore and is  incompatible with the net8.
So, is there is way to unit-test platform-specific net8.0-macos class library now? Maybe I can somehow run tests with standard xUnit/NUnit/msTest? Maybe there are some custom test runners exist for such a tasks or at least experiments/prototypes/etc?
Note: This is not a seeking for the library recommendations, but mostly about how to use the well-known libraries/tools for a specific task.
